# error within if condition - 'encrypt' expected type 'bool', got unconvertible type 'string'

Tags: config, terragrunt

I'm trying to define a config block for two environments - local and cloud and I'm using the if/else condition but I got an error message for the encrypt attribute of the s3 bucket: 'encrypt' expected type 'bool', got unconvertible type 'string'.
If I remove the if/else condition block then it worked but I need to choose between the two environments, so I've to use if/else condition.
The config block code:

```
config = local.is_local_environment ? {
    # Local configuration
    path = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
  } : {
    # Cloud configuration
    bucket = "my-bucket"
    key = "terraform/${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    region = local.region
    encrypt = true
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-lock"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that local backends don't take any configuration, use null

```
config = local.is_local_environment ? null : {
    # Cloud configuration
    bucket = "my-bucket"
    key = "terraform/${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    region = local.region
    encrypt = true
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-lock"
  }
}
```